# Django CSRF Malfunction after using HTTPS

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, apache2

I know that this problem is occurs many times here. But none of them has working for me right now. I've been struggling in this error since I change the protocol of my app to https using apache2 and LetsEncrypt. I try the configurations in settings but it doesn't solve the problem.

```
# settings.py
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".myapp.ml"
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE =  True
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Ofcourse in every forms with POST method required that I have has `{% csrf_token %}` in there. It also shows in request data. This errors occurs in Log in and Sign Up forms.

Inside the app after I add csrf_exempt in login and signup, I use DRF and when I make requests like POST, DELETE, PUT etc... It only shows the error `{"detail":"CSRF Failed: Referer checking failed - no Referer."}`

Here is my apache2 configuration file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName www.myapp.ml
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /app /home/app/app-src/static_root
        <Directory /home/app/app-src/static_root>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/app/app-src/media
        <Directory /home/app/app-src/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/app/app-src/Project>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/app/app-src/Project/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess Project python-path=/home/app/app-src python-home=/home/app/app-src/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup Project

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
WSGIPassAuthorization On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myapp.ml/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myapp.ml/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**NOTE:** That is only occuring when I use the HTTPS protocol.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
I start to find the bug here and I found it on my OWN HTML FILE! I Literally forgot that one of my meta tags set the referrer to no-referrer so I just replace it with origin then everything works fine.